# Get the name of ONE element when it is clicked in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm wondering how I can get the name of an element when it is clicked in PHP, but all elements have the same name for this instance...

PHP:

```
<?php
    $playlist_names = array("Chill", "Groovy", "Pastasauce", "Dank Songs", "Katy Perry");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($playlist_names); $i++) {
        echo "<a href=\"\" class=\"playlist-name\" name=\"$x\">$playlist_names[$i]<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/pLLny9D.png\" class=\"gear-icon\" /></a>";
    }
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is when "playlist-name" is clicked - It will return the playlist name in a different div with the text "Editing [Name of the playlist here]"

This does seem like a simple problem, but as always thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).text();` to get the text inside an html element

for your case to retrive only the first element text you can use this selector :

`$("div p:nth-child(1)").text();`

and so one for the other ones .

Comment: If I was trying to display the name of each element in a different DIV / Dialog Box, It would just return a string like "This is Alpha.This is Beta.This is Gamma.This is Delta", what I'm trying to find out is - How can I just display ONE name not all of them at once

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to do that because long story short I'm working on a music site where the user can edit a playlist and it'll bring up a dialog box with "Editing [Playlist Name]" but I can't do that because if they create many playlists I can't predict the number playlist that they are clicking on hence: "child(250)" - if they have 250 playlists...

Comment: you can loop threw all your p's and get the text of each of'em then use Jquery.each to access the one you are looking for by his index !!

Comment: $(this).text() return text of one current element that is clicked, not all of them.

PS of course you can predict number of p elements, with adding them to array.

Answer (score 0):

here is the link to [Jquery's](http://api.jquery.com/on/) explanation of the on method, which is what you SHOULD be using. as well as the code and a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k73x70xs/) for kicks.

```
//onclick of ANY <p> element with a class of .sample

$( "p" ).on( "click", ".sample", function() {

//do something

alert($( this ).text());

});
```